# Output from grep commands won't write to a file

Tags: grep

My script is set up as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
grep 'zz' <$1> >>output.txt
grep '^.....'<$1> >>output.txt
grep '^...'|'^....' <$1> >>output.txt
grep 'ing$' <$1> >>output.txt
grep '^A' <$1> >>output.txt
grep '[oO]...t' <$1> >>output.txt
```

The goal of the shell script is to read from a given text file ($1) and write it to output.txt, however using the code as it is now throws an error that reads

```
line 2:syntax error near unexpected token '>>'
```

What is incorrect about my script? Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Is your file really named like `<filename>`, that is - that it contains literal `<` and `>`?

Comment: I need to escape those chars to be able to create a file: touch `\<myfile\>` . And to then `ls` that file same thing.